# csrf hash token behaviour when website is open in multiple tabs

Tags: forms, csrf

I am trying to integrate a method to add a hash token to every form in my application. I want to achieve to goals with this:

1. Prevent csrf attacks
2. Prevent that a form gets resubmitted when the user reloads a page after submitting a form

Now, the concept in doing this should be simple enough I thought:

- I generate a unique hash and save it to the cookie
- I create a hidden field in the form with the generated hash
- before processing the $_POST data from the form I verify that the hash value from the form matches the one from the cookie.

So far so good, now what where I really get stuck is the following scenario:

What if a user opens another tab with with my application. Everytime the page gets loaded the hash value gets regenerated. Thus rendering the hash value from the form in the first tab invalid.

Comment: How about just storing a list of currently valid tokens for each user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't store the token as a cookie.

Generate a unique token on each page impression. Upon POST, verify that YOU issued the token (to this user) and verify that it hasn't been used before.

First, we generate a token where we can verify that we issued it for a given user:

`token = hash(session_id + secret)`

That way, using their session id and our secret, we can always verify that we issued that token, since noone knows secret.

Now we need to make sure that the token can only be used once.

```
rnd = rand()
token = rnd + hash(session_id + secret + rnd)
```

The token now has a random number. When a POST happens, we can store this random number as "has been used before" and reject any token that re-uses the same random number.

But we don't want to store random numbers of used tokens forever. So we limit the lifetime of tokens.

```
rnd = rand()
now = time()
token = rnd + time + hash(session_id + secret + rnd + time)
```

On POST, when we get a token we now check if we issued it "recently". We only need to store used random numbers for that same timespan. All older tokens are invalid by definition.

You can safe the used random numbers along with the session id and delete them when you evict the session id or when they become invalid (whichever happens first).

Comment: This is a good, thorough answer. however; most of it isn't directed at the actual question, which was about how to make the codes friendly to multi-tabbed browsing. You mention it almost in passing, and mostly describe (well and correctly, imo) how to create the code... which was not what the OP was asking about.

Comment: Thank you very much for your very detailed answer. I have tried your approach but I am having one problem:

If I save a hash -> timestamp pair with every request and let them expire after lets say 60 minutes there may be hundreds of these hash values in the users session. I am not sure how much data I can save in the session but this way I am cluttering up the session.

Comment: For the random value, you need -let's say- 4 bytes. For the timestamp another 4 bytes. A total of 8 bytes per POST request. Hundreds of those values is still not very much data. If you're not comfortable storing it in your session then put it in some other place. Memcached might be an option. BTW, You should know where your session data is stored. Look it up and learn.

Comment: Andrew: he was looking for CSRF protection. His initial approach was not friendly to multi-tabbed-browsing because it relied on cookies. I showed an approach where he doesn't need cookies, thus being "friendly to multi-tabbed browsing". I just describe how that approach works and why it works, using pseudocode for clarity. I don't see what's wrong with that.

Comment: I save my session as TEXT field in a mysql database. At present I use a 32 character long hash key and the timestamp as you said is 4 bytes in size. So one hash => timestamp pair would be 36 bytes. A mysql field of type TEXT allowes up to 65535 bytes. So if we assume only using the session for the hash keys I could save about 1820 hash keys before running out of space. That is not that many.

Another approach would be to limit the quanity of hash keys to lets say 20 and delete the first key if that quantity is reached.

Comment: So the random number you use for the hash is 32 bytes? Isn't that a bit overkill? You don't need to save the full hash, only the random number plus the expiration timestamp. Also, as you said, if you only need to save this data for the protection against accidental form resubmission, you can limit the number of values stored (You're not protecting against intentional replay attacks) to some fixed value that seems sane.

Comment: I would store an array of array( 0=>array('token1', '2013-12-21 12:20:32'), 1=>array('token2', '2013-12-21 12:21:32') ) so after 30 minutes the array section with token and timestamp gets deleted. I would check and clean this session up at each page refresh. This approach will allow multiple tabs to work by sharing multiple tokens.

Answer (score 1):

I would implement the features independently:

**CSRF prevention**

Use a CSRF token to prevent successful CSRF attacks: Generate a *random* token per session or per URL/form and store it in the session. When a form is initially requested, put the (associated) CSRF token and validate it later when processing the submitted form data.

As the CSRF token is generated by and stored at the server, it cannot be forged by an attacking site and is only valid for that session. Likewise, validation is trivial. The only remaining risk is that an issued CSRF token can be obtained by an attacking site through Cross-Site Scripting (but that would make CSRF somehow obsolete).

**Multiple form submission prevention**

Use a once valid token to prevent multiple submissions: Generate a *unique* token for every initial form request and put it in the form. On form submission, check whether that token has already been used and remember it as used.

To only allow tokens that had been issued by your server, you can use some sort of [message authentication algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code). And to lower the number of tokens to remember, you could make the token expire sometime so that you just have to remember the tokens of a specific timeframe.

Multiple tabs or form requests are no problem: The CSRF token is valid either during the whole session or for any form submission of a specific URL/form. And the other token is only valid for a single form submission.